# Pandas - Make new columns by taking the row difference of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with up to 500 cols and want to make new columns by taking the absolute difference between each row (for each column) and save it in a new set of 500 columns.

For example with 3 columns:

```
A  B  C
4  6  1
8  9  6 
9  3  7
2  2  1
```

Would create: (with AdBdCd being the difference for each row in ABC):

```
A  B  C Ad Bd Fd
4  6  1  -  -  -
8  9  6  4  3  5
9  3  7  1 -6  2
2  2  1 -7 -1 -6
```

My pseudocode looks like this;

```
col_names = ['A','B','C']
df[col_names & '_difference'] = df[col_names] - df[col_names].shift(-1)
```

However that naming for assignment certainly doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a typo in the A column? Should the 12 in your first df be a 9?

Comment: Yeah I changed it for formatting, forgot to change the first df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.concat([df, df.diff().add_suffix('_diff')], axis=1)`

`print(df)`

```
   A  B  C  A_diff  B_diff  C_diff
0  4  6  1     NaN     NaN     NaN
1  8  9  6     4.0     3.0     5.0
2  9  3  7     1.0    -6.0     1.0
3  2  2  1    -7.0    -1.0    -6.0
```

Comment: This makes the columns but with the same name. How do I add a string to the col names to differentiate them? IE. 'A' become 'A_diff'.

Comment: Did not know about `.add_suffix`! Very nice, thank you.